# Selecting first child of ancestor using Xpath from descendant node

Tags: xml, xpath

Here's my XML:

```
<c01>
 <did>
  <unittitle>Title</unittitle>
 </did>
 <c02>
  <did>
   <unittitle>Title</unittitle>
  </did>
 </co2>
 <c02>
  <did>
   <unittitle>Title</unittitle>
  </did>
 </co2>
 <c02>
  <did>
   <unittitle>Title</unittitle>
  </did>
 </co2>
</c01>
```

The active node is `<did>` as I'm working on a template. From any `c02/did` what XPATH do I use to select only the first `c02` child of `c01`?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
../../c02[1]
```

This expression walks up two nodes from `c02/did` to `c01` and then selects the first `c02` child.

Comment: Logically, I understand that should work. Unfortunately, it's not wokring in my stylesheet. Something else must be interfering; will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

`<xsl:if test=".. is ../../c02[1]">`

Thanks, Martin and Wendell.